# Wrong password with basic auth and docker features from traefik 1.3.0

Tags: authentication, docker, traefik

I tried the release 1.3.0 of traefik but I was unable to make the basic auth work. Here is what I did, can you point out my mistake(s) (if there is/are), please?

I'm working on a Macbook pro, with docker 17.03.1-ce, build c6d412e.

1. I followed the [docker swarm mode tutorial](https://docs.traefik.io/user-guide/swarm-mode/) from traefik documentation with one node on my localhost (no docker machine)

   - `docker swarm init`
   - `docker network create --driver=overlay traefik-net`
   - `docker service create \
     --name traefik \
     --constraint=node.role==manager \
     --publish 80:80 --publish 8080:8080 \
     --mount type=bind,source=/var/run/docker.sock,target=/var/run/docker.sock \
     --network traefik-net \
     traefik \
     --docker \
     --docker.swarmmode \
     --docker.domain=traefik \
     --docker.watch \
     --web`
   - `docker service create \
     --name whoami \
     --label traefik.port=80 \
     --network traefik-net \
     emilevauge/whoami`
   - http://localhost:8080 gives me traefik dashboard with `whoami` added as frontend and backend
   - `curl -H Host:whoami.traefik http://localhost` gives the expected result

     > Hostname: d0ad61fcffa6 ...
2. I deleted and recreated whoami with basic auth label, the one from [documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/toml/#docker-backend):

   - `docker service rm whoami`
   - `docker service create \
     --name whoami \
     --label traefik.port=80 \
     --label traefik.frontend.auth.basic=test:$apr1$H6uskkkW$IgXLP6ewTrSuBkTrqE8wj/,test2:$apr1$d9hr9HBB$4HxwgUir3HP4EsggP/QNo0 \
     --network traefik-net \
     emilevauge/whoami`
   - http://localhost:8080 gives me traefik dashboard with `whoami` added as frontend and backend
   - `curl -H Host:whoami.traefik http://localhost` gives me 401 as expected
   - `curl -H Host:whoami.traefik -u test:test http://localhost` gives me 401 which is not expected
   - `curl -H Host:whoami.traefik -u test2:test2 http://localhost` gives me 401 which is not expected

Any idea why basic auth doesn't work in my case?

Regards

Comment: Did you quote or escape the $ on the docker service create command?

Comment: lol... I copied/pasted the values like a dumb. Works fine. Thanks for point out my mistake.

Comment: @Pierre-JeanVardanéga you're the only one in internet specified how to pass basic auth in docker